# Llenar una JTable desde una clase, con datos de una base de datos en MYsql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jframe

En mi proyecto tengo un `JFrame` donde tiene una tabla de nombre `tblbbregistrado`. Necesito crear un método en una clase llamada `Bebe` que haga la consulta a `SQL` y me envíe los datos de la consulta a la tabla.

El código es el siguiente:

**Bebe.java**

```
public void consultabb(String dato){

    String [] titulo={"Expediente","Nombre","Fecha"};
    String[] registros=new String [3];
    String sql="SELECT * FROM paciente WHERE expediente like '%"+dato+"%'  ORDER BY expediente";
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulo);
    try {
        Statement st= cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            registros [0]=rs.getString("expediente");
            registros [1]=rs.getString("nombre");
            registros [2]=rs.getString("fecha");

            modelo.addRow(registros);
        } 
        principal modelos = new principal();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error al consultar pacientes registrados");
    }
}
```

Éste es el código de la clase que quiero que haga la consulta a `MySQL` y envíe los datos a la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

para ello Necesitaremos rescastar los Datos de mi BD y utilizar lo correspondiente para agregarlos a nuestra JTable.

```
POR AQUI TE APORTO MI CODIGO.

import javax.swing.*;

class EjemploTabla extends JFrame{

   public EjemploTabla(){

        setTitle("Pones titulo");

        setBunds(Das dimensiones);

        add(new LaminaTabla());

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) => AQUI CIERRA EL FRAME

     }
 }

class LaminaTabla extends JPanel{

  public LaminaTabla(){

      RescataDatos();

    }


 private void RescataDatos(){

   Connection miConexion = "AQUI CONECTAS CON TU BD";

   String sql = "SELECT * FROM MI BD";

   Statement sentencia = miConexion.createStatement(sql);

   ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery();

   while(resultado.next()){

     Aqui viene lo interesando si tu BD tiene 2 campos String haces lo siguiente.

     Asi lo haces con los demas datos, me imagino que ya sabes rescatar datos.

     String s1 = resultado.getString(1);

     String s2 = resultado.getString(2);

   }
    String columnas[] = {"columna1", "columna2"}

    Object filas[][]= {{s1,s2}};

    JTable mitabla = new JTable(filas,columnas);
  }

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, intentare